# Execute script inside docker container which is folder different than WORKDIR

Tags: docker

I'm inside my docker container:
This is my working directory

```
root@19b84a014662:/usr/src/ghost#
```

I have a script in:

```
root@19b84a014662:/
```

I'm able to cd to `/` and execute the script. But I need to execute the script from my docker-compose file. I tried

```
./test.sh
```

But this actually means it's searching in `/usr/src/ghost/` for the script instead of `/`
How can I execute the script, in the `/` of my container?

Example: I ssh into my container:

```
root@19b84a014662:/usr/src/ghost# ls
Gruntfile.js  LICENSE  PRIVACY.md  README.md  config.example.js  config.js  content  core  index.js  node_modules  npm-shrinkwrap.json  package.json
```

I have a script in the root of my container. I want to execute it with:

```
./test.sh
```

Than it show me only folders/scripts which are in `/usr/src/ghost` and not in `/`

```
root@19b84a014662:/usr/src/ghost# ./
content/      core/         node_modules/
```

Comment: `/test.sh` or `RUN /test.sh` in a Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `./test.sh` by

```
/test.sh
```

Because `./` means you're starting from current directory (which is the working dir `/usr/src/ghost/` in this case). Inspite of this `/` means you're starting from root directory and that's what you want to do.

Alternatively you could switch to root dir and execute your script in one command using the `&&` concatenator below. But I'll recommend the above.

```
cd / && ./test.sh
```